# The escape key doesn't produce the \[AliasDelimeter] special character

Tags: front-end

For some reason the escape key no longer produces the three vertical lines or the \[AliasDelimiter] special character anymore making it very tedious to write greek letters.

I was able to bind the task to "a"+"Command"+"Control" for example, by changing the short name delimiters line in the "KeyEventTranslations.tr" file. But combinations with the escape key don't work.

Any help is appreciated in resolving this!

Note: I am currently using version 12.3.1.0 running on a Mac OS X ARM platform.

Comment: Might be a Mac issue with the mac version, Esc still produces \[AliasDelimiter] in Ver 13.1 on Windows.

Comment: The problem was in fact a Mac issue. Specifically it was due to errors with Siri, where the background process would get stuck running. This somehow causes the escape key to not work under certain circumstances. Disabling Siri altogether seems to have fixed the issue.